# How to handle the first '%' in a cron command?

Tags: cron

I don't fully understand `man cron`, and the handling of the first `%` symbol.

Unlike most questions about % in a `crontab` file, I'd actually **like** to use % as newline. What do I need to do with the first % so it isn't interpreted as either a literal "%" symbol, or a change/redirect of stdin? I don't quite understand what it's doing and what to do if I dont need it.

Example crontab line:

```
0 0 * * *  root  newline="%" %echo "this${newline}that" %command2 %command3
```

(I know I could use semicolons or \n for some, but using %-newline for the sake of this example)

## Update:

As comments seem to miss the point, this is the issue:

> **man crontab(5)**
>
> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or a "%" character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile.
>
> **... A "%" character in the command, unless escaped with a backslash (), will be changed into newline characters ...**
>
> **... and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.**

I well understand that as written, the crontab line I've given won't currently work. I understand that unescaped % *after the first* -> newline (first bold point). What I don't understand is the second bold point.

If all I want to do is use % to insert newlines, this implies I need to do something different with the first unescaped "%", to avoid it being treated as an unintended trigger to "send all subsequent data to the command as stdin". That might mean putting an extra "%" at the start of the command, or whatever, to ensure the first % doesnt disrupt the rest of the command's handling.

Some examples of a line with 2 or 3 unescaped %'s, showing how cron will interpret the first unescaped % and what that does in command handling, would be ideal.

Also, is the second bold point to be taken literally? If so, I can use a 2nd ofr subsequent unescaped % to act as a newline, essentially my command can contain a multiline script after % -> newline substitution, before passing to shell. is that correct?

Comment: To tell cron that you want a literal % instead of a newline, use \%. If you omit the backslash, everything after the first % becomes standard input. If I understand this right, the example won't work.

Comment: What do you want to happen? What output are you expecting?

Comment: OP updated to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the crontab, the part after the time specifications and up to the first unescaped `%` makes up the code to be passed to the shell (as the argument after `sh` and `-c`). What comes after that first `%` makes up lines to be fed to that shell via its stdin.

In effect, with a crontab line such as:

```
* * * * * shell code%line 1%line 2
```

`cron` does every minute the equivalent of this shell code:

```
printf '%s\n' 'line 1' 'line 2' | sh -c 'shell code'
```

So you can't really use it to store a newline character in a variable of that `shell code`.

Here, if you want a newline stored in a variable in that code, you can do

```
* * * * * eval "$(printf 'nl="\n"')"; echo "blah${nl}blah"
```

You could however make the code be just `sh`, and then feed the code on stdin:

```
* * * * * sh%nl='%'%echo "blah${nl}blah"
```

In that one, `cron` will run `sh -c sh`, and the stdin of the process that executes that `sh` that executes another `sh` will be:

```
nl='
'
echo "blah${nl}blah"
```

Another option is to tell `cron` to use a shell that supports the ksh93-style `$'...'` form of quotes (like `ksh93`/`zsh`/`bash`) instead of `sh` and do:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
* * * * * nl=$'\n'; echo "blah${nl}blah"
```

Comment: To test understanding, would this be a working command?: `cat%echo "line 1%line 2"` ? Interpreted as equivalent to `echo "line 1\nline 2" | cat` ?

Comment: @Stilez, that would be more like `echo 'echo "line 1<newline>line2"' | cat`. Or `printf '%s\n' 'echo "line 1' 'line 2"' | cat`.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!!